# Add all .css to child themes at one time, or right way to do it one by one?

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

How to use functions.php to add all the .css to child themes at one time?
If it is not possible at once, how is right way to do it one by one?

Theme: Generatepress
https://sk.wordpress.org/themes/generatepress/

Child: Hand made by Codex
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 0):

Adding one CSS file isn't recommended, it's better if you register each new custom CSS individually.

Keep in mind, a child theme will automatically inherit all of the parent's CSS. You should only register CSS files you custom wrote.

This is an example function of loading a CSS file located in the CSS directory within the child theme. It loads a custom file 'CustomFooter.css' on a page with an ID of 45.

```
 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'footer_css' );
      function footer_css() {
          if (is_page(45)) {
              wp_enqueue_style('CustomFooter-style',  
 get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
 '/CSS/CustomFooter.css?v=1.1', array( 'parent-style'));
      }
 }
```